# How to generate all the combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, number-representation

There are $N$ optimization variables, $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_N$.
and $v_n\in{0,1,2,3,\cdots,K}$.

Let $N=10$ and $K=5$.

How can I generate all the possible combinations?

For example, the first combination is $[0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0]$

The last combination is $[5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 5]$

${\bf EDIT}$: Then I need to filter out the tuples that do not give sum (of elements) exactly equal to 5.

Using

IntegerPartitions[5,{10},range[0,5]] is giving me some of the possible combinations, not all!

For example, its giving {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0} as one of the candidate, but does not give {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1} as another candidate.

Comment: Do you really want to generate them all? There 6^10 such tuples. I can't believe you have enough memory to store them.

Comment: try `Tuples[Range[0,5],10]`

Comment: @J42161217, Thank you. Please see my edit. How can I now filter out the tuples that give sum more than 5 or any given number?.

Comment: This can be done with `IntegerPartitions` more or less as in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105139/generating-tuples-with-restrictions). For example, try `Table[IntegerPartitions[sum, {10}, Range[0, 5]], {sum, 6, 5 10}]`. I think this almost has an answer in the linked question already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate the lists of $0 \leq m \leq X$ integer values so these values add up to $X$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179292/how-to-generate-the-lists-of-0-leq-m-leq-x-integer-values-so-these-values-ad) as well as many others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Select[Tuples[Range[0,5],10],Total@#<=5&]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Permutations` together with `IntegerPartitions`:

```
With[{n = 10, k = 5},
  Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[0, n]]]
```

> {{5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>   {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, ..., {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

(2002 solutions in total).

There are $\binom{k+n-1}{k}$ solutions in total, which is a very small fraction of all $(k+1)^n$ tuples that you suggest to list and then filter (as in J42161217's solution). Better to do a direct construction like what I wrote above.